# Синтаксический разбор

Tags: подлежащее, синтаксис

В предложении "Нападало много снега" ученица увидела нераспространенное двусоставное предложение с подлежащим, выраженным неделимым синтаксическим целым. Учитель исправил ответ: предложение односоставное безличное. Кто прав?

Answer (score 1):

Ученица! 5 веток, много веток, много снега - количественное сочетание в роли подлежащего.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, и тот, и другой прав.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, действительно, дискуссионный и неоднозначный.

При классификации предложений по семантически-структурному методу выделяется класс количественно-бытийных безличных предложений. Они утверждают наличие чего-л. в достаточном/недостаточном количестве: Времени хватает/не хватает. Сил прибавилось/убавилось.Снегу намело! Однако в этих предложениях используется Р.п.

Сравним: Нападало много снега. - Снега нападало! Семантика предложений одинаковая и характерная для безличных предложений: описывается природный процесс, происходящий сам собой. Можно также задать вопрос: а какой падеж у "много снега", ведь у слова "много" только две формы: много - по многу? Кажется, что есть все основания считать предложение безличным.

Тем не менее, в грамматике неоднозначное решение имеет сходное по форме предложение "Собралось много народу." В школьной классификации оно считается двусоставным. А вот предложение "Дел прибавилось" в школе определяют как  односоставное. Скорее всего, это формальное решение по наличию субъекта в И.п. Тогда "Народу собралось!" следует считать уже безличным.

Но как всё-таки ответить школьнику? "Нападало много снега". Можно сказать, что формально это двусоставное предложение, а по семантике оно ближе к односоставному безличному.